# Understanding the effect of PDE solution on critical strip?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ap.analysis-of-pdes, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, linear-pde

I would like to understand a little bit about how to interpret and construct $1$-parameter gamma factors that are dynamical - that is they are particular solutions to linear PDE's. Some possible motivation for this is that we might be able to understand parts of the critical strip in terms of an evolution equation inextricably tied to the functional equation.

Although the usual gamma factor is easy to work with, from my understanding, a drawback of using this gamma factor, $\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2),$ is that there's no obvious way to insert a parameter into the expression s.t. it satisfies a linear partial differential equation. Perhaps this follows from some argument along the lines of Hölder's theorem.

After some careful analysis I found a working example using the family of even Schwartz functions $f_r(x)=\exp \frac{r}{\log |x|}$ on the interval $-1<x<1$ and for $r>0$.

$$\Gamma(f_r,s):=\int_{\mathbb R^\times \cap ~(0,1)} |x|^s~f_r(x)~{dx\over |x|}=2 \sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{r s})$$

for Bessel function $K_1$.

Then the $ 1$-parameter family of functional equations reads $$\Gamma(f_r,s)\cdot \zeta(s) \;=\; \Gamma(\hat{f}_r,1-s)\cdot \zeta(1-s)$$

where $\hat f$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$.

Isolating $\Gamma(f_r,s)$ we obtain

$$\Gamma(f_r,s) \;=\; \Gamma(\hat{f}_r,1-s)\cdot \frac{\zeta(1-s)}{\zeta(s)}$$

Since the LHS satisfies

$$r^2 \frac{\partial ^3}{\partial r^3}\Gamma(f_r,s) =s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Gamma(f_r,s) \tag{1}$$

through equality we have that the RHS satisfes this PDE as well. This effectively maps the PDE onto the critical strip and encodes the Gamma factor into this evolution equation tied to the $1$-parameter family of functional equations.

In fact, the holomorphic extension of $f_r(x)$ through the Wick rotation satisfies a sort of Schrödinger wave equation in the absence of force, with a $+$ sign instead of a $-$ sign. And taking the Fourier transform of the LHS of $(1)$ w.r.t. $r$ yields again, the same Schrödinger wave equation, but the Fourier transform, $\hat \Gamma$, doesn't exist.

> What is the effect of the functional equation satisfying $(1)$ on the critical strip especially on the line $s=1/2\pm it$?

I know there is a differential relationship at play but I'm not sure how it actively transforms the critical line and nontrivial zeros.

I know that $(1)$ is used to model linear dispersion of water waves, plasma waves, elastic media etc. My initial condition for $(1)$ is $\Gamma(f_r,s)_{|_{r=0}}$.